# React Native Exception thrown while executing UI block: *** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]

Tags: reactjs, iphone, react-native, twilio-video

I'm building an iOS react-native app, and I'm currently using the react-native-twilio-video-webrtc to build audio/video calling for my app. The app works fine on iPad however when I go to run the app on iPhone, and have audio/video call when the call accepted from the call recipient  I'm getting the following error:

Error setting property 'enabled' of RCTTWLocalVideoView with tag #1053:
Exception thrown while executing UI block: *** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray

[image: Error Screen shot]